# Store HTML template in NoSQL DB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, nosql

I am working with AWS Lambda/DynamoDb  in Java and want to store an HTML template to the dynamo db for mailing purpose.
My problem statement : 
I have to use a HTML template to send mails to end users.

**Solution i implemented:**

**Solution 1 :**  Store the template in s3 download the template, change the place holders and mail it.
issue with solution -> When i test this in my local system, everything works fine but after i upload this to lamda and then execute the function then it doesn't work.

I get the following error message:-

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1.html (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1.html (Permission denied)
```

**My code is -**

```
 String bucketName = "abc";
        String key = "xyz/1.html";
        String fileName = "1.html";

        ObjectMetadata s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                bucketName, key), new File(fileName));
```

The catch is that this exact script works in my local machine so i am sure that the key and the bucketname matches to the correct file.

**Solution 2 :** 
Store the html template in Dynamodb and when needed replace the place holders and then send the mail. 
The issue that as Dynamo db is a key value db so double quotes are not allowed. So i need to escape them. I can save the template by escaping the template's double quotes but then what about the time when i need to take them back from the db and then remove all the escape sequences again. ? Is this a correct process, if yes then how to achieve this ?

so my questions are :

1. how to implement solution 1.
2. Is there any api or some other way to first escape and then remove the escapes in HTML template ?
3. Is there some better way to solve my problem case.

Comment: Do you have the right [permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html) set up for your Lambda function?

Comment: yes @mkobit. i have verified from the link u provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solution 1, when you download the file from S3, write it to the /tmp directory.

i.e. /tmp/1.html

/tmp is the only filesystem directory that your lambda can write to.